# c++ CDialog ID change

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cdialog

I have a CDialog class and i need it to be called by a sum of other classes, at the same time.  This should work from what i understand, but it would be the same instance of the Dialog, and i need as many different instances as calling classes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each dialog window displayed on the screen simultaneously must have a different CDialog derived object associated with it. They may all be the same class, with the same resource ID, but they must be different objects.

Comment: So, if a member of an object changes it's state, this won't reflect in the state of other same objects?

Comment: @MRM, yes that's the difference between a class and an object. Each object has its own members that are distinct from other objects of the same class.